# Serializer field for side effect model django rest framework

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a `django.db.models.Model` `A` whose instances are created in a `rest_framework.serializers.ModelSerializer` from POST requests.

Depending on the data being sent in the POST, I would like to create one of several other "addon" models, let's say `B` or `C`, which I link to the original through a `django.db.models.OneToOneField`:

```py
from django.db import models

class A(models.Model):
    some_field = models.CharField()

class B(models.Model):
    a = models.OneToOneField(A, related_name='addon', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class C(models.Model):
    a = models.OneToOneField(A, related_name='addon', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

What I would like to is to have a serializer which validates the incoming data, including some string indicating which addon to use. The serializer then creates the model instance of `A` and based on this creates the addon model.

I do not want to create a utility field in model `A` used to determine which addon to use, I would like to create the model directly using the instance of model `A` and information from the POST itself.

At the same time when accessing the data through a get, I would like to return the original string used to determine which addon to use.

What I have come up with so far:

```py
from rest_framework import serializers

str2model = {'b': B, 'c': C}

class AddonField(serializers.Field):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        # I completely ignore "value" as no "internal value" is set in "to_internal_value"
        myvalue = self.parent.instance.addon
        for addon_name, addon_class in str2model.items():
            if isinstance(myvalue, addon_class):
                return addon_name

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        # I create the "internal value" after "A" instance is created, thus here I do nothing?
        return data

class ASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    some_field = serializers.CharField()
    the_addon = AddonField()

    def validate_the_addon(self, value): # here addon is a string
        if value in str2model.keys():
           return value

    def create(self, validated_data):
        addon_name = validated_data.pop('the_addon')
        addon_class = str2model[addon]
        a = super(ASerializer, self).create(validated_data)
        addon_class.objects.create(a=a)
        return a    

    class Meta:
        model = A
        fields = ["some_field", "the_addon"]
```

When testing this I get:

`` AttributeError: Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `the_addon` on serializer `ASerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `A` instance.
Original exception text was: 'A' object has no attribute 'the_addon'. ``

How can I temporarily store `the_addon` in the serializer until the `A` instance has been created?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would typically approach it

```
# Serializer

class ASerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    some_field = serializers.CharField()
    addon_b = serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_null=True)
    addon_c = serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_null=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        addon_b = validated_data.pop('addon_b')
        addon_c = validated_data.pop('addon_c')
        a = A.objects.create(some_field=validated_data['some_field'])

        if addon_b:
            B.objects.create(a=a)

        if addon_c:
            C.objects.create(a=a)

        return a
```

You can do other validations if necessary.

```
class TestAPIView01(generics.CreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = {}
    serializer_class = serializers.ASerializer
    queryset = A.objects.all()
```

Also, look at the `related_name` on `B` and `C` you may want to consider making them different, as that might throw an error in the future. Cheers